# Make white molecular particles on the outside and red on the inside?

Tags: particles, eevee-render-engine

I have been struggling to try to make the inside of my molecular mannequin red (to sort of representing blood) and the outside white. For a [reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Itp5TyTO2Mc) ...

[image]

I have now aimed for a collection of white/red spheres, have tried count, random, and so on without coming close to what I want.

I want to render it in Eevee any suggestions? Something I can do in the shading tab?

Here is my try ...
[image]

Comment: @ChrisAnderson Do you use molecular add-on for some simulation or a build in grid distribution. Do you plan any animation or physics simulation?

Comment: Hi yes, I use the molecular add-on for the simulations for particals, and I have assigned a group of sphere as particals. Is that I want white particles on the outside and red on the inside.

Comment: Yes, it is an animation where it spits the mannequin. with collision.

Comment: thanks for your answer. want to achieve this effect https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Itp5TyTO2Mc and been bugging me for a couple of days now haha

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if reference object in your linked video is done by the same way, but you can try ...

- for outer particles - add Solidify modifier to your object
- for inner particles - copy outer object, Apply modifier, go to edit mode select one outer vertex, select Linked <kbd>L</kbd>, delete, Recalculate Normals <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

Like this you create "inset" object without overlapping particles.

[image]

Enable under Collision

- Activate Collision with others
  Enable under links
- Activate Particles linking with others

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Id did finally make it work, did ended up with doing to models, and putting the outer layer on the face and making the inner model set to volume. But think that thickness would probably make it easier.

Here is the result :-)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xA6bcbLOUkw

Cheers and thanks for the help.